# Not Aligning the data inside a column in pdf generated by using jspdf auto table

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have attached my problem in the below snap , I dont know how to align the data in particular manner inside a column using jspdf-autotable generated pdf.
I have a requirement to show the parent step and child step in a column . so In my code I wrote a logic inside `drawCell()` for every child step, added 10Spaces and print in pdf. 
Inside `drawCell()` I got cell.text data in the form of array of Strings. I easily added 10 spaces for every string like below

`["      String1","      String2","      String3","     TOOLONG STRING dfhdjhdfd..fsdd..."]`

If the String is too long some of the letters are hided at the edge of the row ,jspdf tries to place a every string in the same line ,below image shows the problem I am highlighted in that, Please give me some suggestion I am not getting any Idea How to fix it ..Please bear with my English

[image: Hided some letters at edge of column]

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the createdCell hook instead of the drawCell hook to add the spaces. It is executed before the width is calculated.